# when I pass an empty string into includes("") will it always return true?

Tags: javascript, methods

So, I am testing the JS includes() method, so I created a search input field, where I can search through the notes I created with live rerendering. Now my question is: 
When I pass no searchtext at all, all the notes are shown, but when I enter a character or a word, the notes get filtered right away. 
Example code:

```js
const filters = {
  searchText: ''
}

// Render application notes
const renderNotes = (notes, filters) => {
  const filteredNotes = notes.filter((note) => {

    return note.title.toLowerCase().includes(filters.searchText.toLowerCase())
  })
  document.querySelector('#notes').innerHTML = ''

  filteredNotes.forEach((note) => {
    const noteEl = generateNoteDOM(note)
    document.querySelector('#notes').appendChild(noteEl)
  })
}
```

I understand from this, that true is always returned in such a case..
Would appreciate any clarification to this subject!

Thanks!

Comment: Is that not the expected and preferred solution?

Comment: yes it is, I was just wondering, if my logic is right... :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `.includes()` function has to match the functionality of `.indexOf()` for consistency, and `.indexOf()` always matches the empty string in any target string. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> An empty string searchValue will match at any index between 0 and str.length.

It's a *little* counter-intuitive, but consider this:

```
var str = "something";
console.log(str.includes("")); // Imagine this returns false ...
str += "";
console.log(str.includes("")); // !!
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding your own version of `.includes()` as below

```js
String.prototype.includes = function(subStr) {
        if (subStr.length == 0 || this.indexOf(subStr) === -1 ) {
                return false;
        }
        return true;
};

var name = "JavaScript";
console.log(name.includes("")); // false
console.log(name.includes(" ")); // false
console.log(name.includes("J")); // true
```